# How to remove link from rendered node title in view?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have added a field to the view displaying a Taxonomy Term: Rendered Taxonomy Term

http://freelance-graphic-designer.us/barmaiddev2/product-category/commercial-juicers

I want to remove the link from the title Commercial Juicers

After reading other posts, I have found the template file `node.tpl.php` and copied it to the template folder of my theme; and renamed it to `node--taxonomy-term.tpl.php`

Then removed the link, and changed the following code from:

```
<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url ?>" title="<?php print $title ?>"><?php print $title ?></a></h2>
```

To this:

```
<h2><?php print $title; ?></h2>
```

I don't know PHP, so this was a guess. It did not work.

Comment: clear Drupal cache

Comment: You need to use tpl from modules/taxonomy/taxonomy-term.tpl.php.  Copy it into theme folder and remove link from it.